# How to establish adb connection between local mobile device and remote ubuntu server to run android automation scripts?

Tags: adb, appium, appium-android

I have deployed automation script in remote ubuntu-server and i want to  execute those script on my local mobile device or emulator.

I have googled for the answer but all the solutions work only if both the device are connected to same wifi network  below is the syntax

adb connect ip address:port

when i run the adb connect in my remote server i should be able to access my local emulator or device connected in some other network

Comment: Do you have public IP address for your internal network?

Comment: yes i tried to establish connection using public IP but it is not working.